# How to send more than 4kb from google cloud function to end user

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-messaging

I have written an app which lets the user upload an image with handwritten text and now he/she should receive the extracted text as 'normal' (digital) text.

Currently, I upload the image to a **google cloud bucket**, which then triggers a **cloud function**, that calls the vision api. The vision api then returns a `JSON` result inside of the cloud function.

Now my question: How can I send the JSON result back to the client?

- I've tried FCM but the JSON response of the `vision api` is more than 4000 bytes, so the message fails to send. (I also need the coordinates of the recognized text). Getting the following error:

```
...
errorInfo: {
    code: 'messaging/invalid-argument',
    message: 'Request contains an invalid argument.' 
}
```

- I've heared of PubSub but as they described [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview#service-to-service_vs_service-to-client_communication) , it is not a good use for *service-to-client communication*. Or is it an option never the less?

**How can I send the "big" result from my cloud function back to the client?**

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks for your time, if anything is unclear or missing I'm happy to add the information asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use FCM to send the actual payload of the vision API to the user. Instead, store the payload in Cloud Storage or a cloud database (such as Firebase's Firestore or Realtime Database) and send the location to the user through FCM in a data property. Your application code can then take that data property, and read the actual API response when the user is ready for it.

Answer (score 0):

Often GCS is handy for passing around large objects. You can redirect the request to any large object in GCS.

1. If it's public, just pass a `Location: https://storage.googleapis.com/%3Cbucket-name%3E/some-path/some-file.json` to the caller
2. If the file is private, create a short lived [signed URL](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#getSignedUrl), and redirect to it like above.

This way you don't need to stream the file through your GCF, or even read it for that matter. Let the GCS CDN do the work for you.